# iPhone 3Gs iOS 5.0.1 get Recieved memory warning error and crash the app

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have created slideshow in my app and caching images in "CacheDirectory" of iPhone under "images" folder. After 10-15 minutes of slideshow app received memory warning and suddenly get crash without doing anything. But its not getting memory warning and even crash on iPhone 4 or 4s with same iOS.

Comment: Sounds to me you haven't updated your project to llvm

Comment: No, I am using latest SDK 5.0 and it has LLVM as default compiler...

Comment: show snippet of your code where leak is occuring and error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone 4 and 4S both have more memory than the 3GS, so if you have a memory leak, or just use a lot of memory the memory warning would come at a later point on the 4/4S.

Wether or not you save the images in the cache directory has no impact on memory usage. You must be keeping more images in memory than possible. When implementing a slideshow that can handle an arbitrary number of images you would have to make sure that images that are not currently displayed are released.